# Updating pivot table with checkbox

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a users table and a services table. I made a many-many pivot table to store which user offers which services. When I try to check or uncheck a service checkbox in my profile blade to modify the user the data is not inserted or removed in the pivot table.

User Model:

```
public function services(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Service::class);
    }
```

Service Model:

```
public function user(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

My code in store function in ProfileController:

```
$user = Auth::user();
    if(isset($request->services)){
                foreach($request->services as $service_id){
                    $service=Service::find($service_id);
                    $service->user()->syncWithoutDetaching($user->id);
                }
        }
```

Blade:

```
<div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Type de services</label>

            <label for="peinture">Peinture</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="peinture" name="services[]" value="1" 
            <?php if (in_array(1, $services->toArray())) echo "checked" ?> >

            <label for="neige">Déneigement</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="neige" name="services[]" value="2"
            <?php if (in_array(2, $services->toArray())) echo "checked" ?> >

            <label for="gardiennage">Gardiennage</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="gardiennage" name="services[]" value="3"
            <?php if (in_array(3, $services->toArray())) echo "checked" ?> >

            <label for="entretien">Entretien paysager</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="entretien" name="services[]" value="4"
            <?php if (in_array(4, $services->toArray())) echo "checked" ?> >
    </div>
```

If I do dd($request); everything seems in it. No clue what I'm doing wrong, thanks for any help.

Comment: Pls read the tag description before using a tag, they my refer to different concepts, not the one you thought of!

Comment: `syncWithoutDetaching()` only adds new IDs but does not remove the existing data. Your code looks okay, just double check if `$user` has a user model. I doubt the user might not be logged in.

Comment: @ZeshanKhattak I'm not sure what you mean. I do have a User model. The first block of code is from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to iterate the services in your controller. just do this:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->services()->sync($request->services);
```

this will first clean the pivot table, then will attach the new values all at once.

i really encourage you not to use $request values without validating them. in this case run this before start syncing the pivot table:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'services' => 'required|array',
    'services.*' => 'exists:services,id',
]);
```

Comment: I added your code and now everything is working thanks a lot! To be fair my validation is a complete mess right now. As for no need to iterate you mean the foreach is useless?

Comment: yes exactly. the sync method generate only one sql query (insert into pivot values (...), (...), (...) ...) while foreach generates an individual query for each service_id @VincentDesrosiers